# I want to use camera on background service using mobile vision

Tags: android, android-vision

I make a android app for my project.
My application's purpose is detection for blinking of eye.

I use a mobile vision api.
I am using a sample code about face detection of mobile vision with blink detection code.

1. My first question is that mobile vision api can be working on background service?
2. My second question is what combine camera api with mobile-vision api?
   The camera api can work on background service but it can't use with mobile-vision face detection class..

please, help me..

My app's service code is

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service{
    private static final String TAG = "FaceTracker";

public CameraSource mCameraSource = null;

public CameraSourcePreview mPreview;
private GraphicOverlay mGraphicOverlay;

private static final int RC_HANDLE_GMS = 9001;
// permission request codes need to be < 256
private static final int RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM = 2;


static int x=0;
//Camera variables
//a surface holder
private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
//a variable to control the camera
private Camera mCamera;
//the camera parameters
private Camera.Parameters parameters;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("SERVICE", "onCreate" );

    // Check for the camera permission before accessing the camera.  If the
    // permission is not granted yet, request permission.
    int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        createCameraSource();
    } else {
        //requestCameraPermission();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Need a permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}


/**
 * Creates and starts the camera.  Note that this uses a higher resolution in comparison
 * to other detection examples to enable the barcode detector to detect small barcodes
 * at long distances.
 */
public void createCameraSource() {
    Log.d("SERVICE", "createCameraSource" );

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setProminentFaceOnly(true) //Detection for front camera
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .build();

    detector.setProcessor(
            new LargestFaceFocusingProcessor(detector, new BlinkTracker()));
    //new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory())
    //.build());

    if (!detector.isOperational()) {
        // Note: The first time that an app using face API is installed on a device, GMS will
        // download a native library to the device in order to do detection.  Usually this
        // completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that download has not yet
        // completed, then the above call will not detect any faces.
        //
        // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native library is currently
        // available.  The detector will automatically become operational once the library
        // download completes on device.
        Log.w(TAG, "Face detector dependencies are not yet available.");
    }

    mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)//using front camera
            .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
            .build();

    Log.i("createCameraSource",mCameraSource.toString());

}

/**
 * starts the camera.
 */

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    startCameraSource();

    // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
    return START_STICKY;
}

/*
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Log.d("SERVICE", "onStart" );
    startCameraSource();
    //startCameraSource();

//    mCamera = Camera.open(1);
}*/




//==============================================================================================
// Camera Source Preview
//==============================================================================================

/**
 * Starts or restarts the camera source, if it exists.  If the camera source doesn't exist yet
 * (e.g., because onResume was called before the camera source was created), this will be called
 * again when the camera source is created.
 */
public void startCameraSource() {
    Log.d("SERVICE", "startCameraSource" );
    // check that the device has play services available.
    int code = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(
            getApplicationContext());
    /*if (code != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Dialog dlg =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, code, RC_HANDLE_GMS);
        dlg.show();
    }*/

    if (mCameraSource != null) {
        try {
            Log.d("startCameraSource", "log!" );
            Log.i("startCameraSource1",mCameraSource.toString());

            mPreview.start(mCameraSource);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
            mCameraSource.release();
            mCameraSource = null;
        }
    }
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


//==============================================================================================
// Eye Blink Tracker
//==============================================================================================

public class BlinkTracker extends Tracker<Face> {
    private final double OPEN_THRESHOLD = 0.85;
    private final double CLOSE_THRESHOLD = 0.50;

    private int state = 0;

    public void onUpdate(Detector.Detections<Face> detections, Face face) {
        Log.i("BlinkTracker", "eye tracker start");
        float left = face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability();
        float right = face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability();
        if ((left == Face.UNCOMPUTED_PROBABILITY) ||
                (right == Face.UNCOMPUTED_PROBABILITY)) {
            // At least one of the eyes was not detected.
            return;
        }

        switch (state) {
            case 0:
                if ((left > OPEN_THRESHOLD) && (right > OPEN_THRESHOLD)) {
                    // Both eyes are initially open
                    Log.i("BlinkTracker", "eye open");
                    state = 1;
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if ((left < CLOSE_THRESHOLD) && (right < CLOSE_THRESHOLD)) {
                    // Both eyes become closed
                    Log.i("BlinkTracker", "blink occurred!");
                    state = 0;
                }
                break;

            /*case 2:
                if ((left > OPEN_THRESHOLD) && (right > OPEN_THRESHOLD)) {
                    // Both eyes are open again
                    Log.i("BlinkTracker", "blink occurred!");
                    state = 0;
                }
                break;*/
        }
    }

}
}
```

logcat

```
07-13 09:55:04.716 17707-17707/com.hyechon.etrackermv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.hyechon.etrackermv, PID: 17707
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.hyechon.etrackermv.ServiceClass@7566889 with Intent { cmp=com.hyechon.etrackermv/.ServiceClass }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.hyechon.etrackermv.camera.CameraSourcePreview.start(com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4079)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1897)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.hyechon.etrackermv.camera.CameraSourcePreview.start(com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.hyechon.etrackermv.ServiceClass.startCameraSource(ServiceClass.java:255)
                                                                        at com.hyechon.etrackermv.ServiceClass.onStartCommand(ServiceClass.java:136)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4062)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1897) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

07-13 09:55:05.666 17707-17777/com.hyechon.etrackermv I/Vision: Connection error: null
07-13 10:00:04.761 17707-17707/com.hyechon.etrackermv I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17707 SIG: 9

Comment: Your variable `mPreview` is not initialized. That's why you are getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: public CameraSourcePreview mPreview = null; 

like this?